# Tengo una prergunta. Es un proyecto final y no sé como validar si un usuario está ya registrado con un username o un correo ya existente en Sqlite

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, aplicación-movil

Tengo una aplicación que es un proyecto final. YA tengo la validación de campos para que no queden vacios. Pero necesito dentro del campo username y email, que me arroje un mensaje de warning si el usuario o el correo ya existe para que no se presenten inconvenientes

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y va a terminar cerrada, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Hola debes agregar lo que trataste, revisa el enlace que te comparte BetaM, saludos.